# monetdb cluster management can't setup

Tags: monetdb

I'm trying to follow MonetDB docs on [Cluster Management](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Cookbooks/SQLrecipes/ClusterManagement)

to setup a 3 nodes cluster using 3 Centos machines, I created the 3 `dbfarm` using `monetdbd create /path/to/mydbfarm` and from the first node, I run `monetdb discover` and it returns nothing where it should discover the other nodes, and when I try to run `monetdb -h [second node IP] -P mypasshphrase status` it returns the following error

> status: cannot connect: Connection refused

PS: I have a passwordless connection between these 3 nodes, `ssh [any node IP]` works just fine,

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default MonetDB listens only for local connections. This is for security reasons.

To listen also for remote connections, run

```
monetdbd set listenaddr=0.0.0.0 .../path/to/dbfarm
```

on each of the nodes and restart monetdbd.

Comment: this solved my problem thank you, but i already have created 3 databases on these 3 nodes and I want to connect them to make up a cluster and rebalance the data, is it doable with MonetDB?