# Cluster configuration on MonetDB: cannot discover other nodes

Tags: monetdb

I have installed and configured a 3 monetdb nodes cluster on 3 virtual machines on my MacBook (Using Oracle Virtual Box). I use MonetDB 5 server 11.37.7

I have followed the [Cluster Management documentation](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/ServerAdministration/ClusterManagement) of MonetDB, but the `monetdb discover` command only returns the dbfarm of the local instance. Each node still isn't aware of other nodes.

I can connect to any nodes from any other node using `monetdb -h [host] -P [passphrase]`, I can also discover the remote farms of a specific host by using `monetdb -h host -P passphrase discover`

The answer to this question [monetdb cluster management can't setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436051/monetdb-cluster-management-cant-setup) helped me in setting the listenaddr property to 0.0.0.0, but still, the discover command only returns the local monetdb farm.

EDIT

Thanks to Jennie suggestion below, I noticed that the monetdb log file contains `error while sending broadcast message: Network is unreachable`.

I used netcat utility to brodcast UDP message from one node to the other 2 and it worked, I can ping, ssh and the 3 nodes are part of the same network configured with virtualbox, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, thanks to @Jennie's post. For anyone using VirtualBox:

- Use the first network adapter of each configured node with `Bridge access` instead of `NAT`
- Configure the following property of your dbfarm: `listenaddr=0.0.0.0`
- For testing purpose, it may be worth reducing the property `discoveryttl` to less than the default 10mns

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution!  I only have basic knowledge about computer networks.  I was about to ask for help from my teammates.

Answer (score 1):

All your VMs must be in the same LAN environment.  `monetdb discover` basically goes over all IP addresses under the same subnet.

Can you some how verify that's the case?

Comment: I configured a host network with VirtualBox and all my VMs are part of this network: 192.168.56.X/24. I even ran nmap -sn 192.168.56.1/24 which discovered my 3 nodes. But I have to mention that 2 network adapters are configured for each VM. 1 as NAT (internet access) and 1 as part of the host network mentioned earlier. Could it be that the `discover` command goes through the NAT one ?

Comment: Well... After hours of trials, I made sure to only have one network interface on each node. They can communicate with each other (ping, nmap, ssh). I used netcat and could brodcast UDP messages from one node to the other 2. So I don't know what happens but monetdb log file says "error while sending broadcast message: Network is unreachable".

Comment: Finally, @Jennie I could make it. I configured my main network interface using Bridge instead of NAT.